# Creating a quiz and summoning questions and answers from extrernal file

Tags: python, authentication

I have a login system in which students take quizzes at different difficulties. what i need to do is load the question and answers for the quiz from an external .txt file. can someone help me quickly please as i need to have this done very soon. can the coding be simple aswell and available to use on python 3.4 as i am not very good with python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This sounds like an excellent opportunity to learn.

Comment: Yeah - we're not going to write it for you (and this is way too vague a description, even if we were inclined to). If you have a specific question, we'll try to help. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you please write it for me. In short what I need is a python 3.4 program (idk if it’s different but I say this version as I see people using print without brackets on other versions) which will summon questions from an external file and the answers to the questions are also in an external file. I need the code to check that the questions are correct aswell. I’m just not sure how to write code which will summon a specific line and check if the answer is correct.

Comment: @H.M I am sorry, but we will not write your full code here, that would be off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can get help, but you must show what you have tried and where you ran into problems so that we can help with a specific programming problem. Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1288408)

Comment: Can you check the answers as i have posted my attempt there

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at the code:

```
def easyMathsQuiz():
score=0
emquiz=open("easymathsquiz.txt","r")
questionNumber=0
for questionNumber,line in enumerate(emquiz):
    print (line)
    ans=input("Your answer is: ")
    if ans == "1":
        score=score+1
        questionNumber=questionNumber+1
    elif ans=="2":
        questionNumber=questionNumber+1
    elif ans !="1" or ans !="2":
        print("You have entered an invalid character")
        easyMathsQuiz()
    break
for questionNumber,line in enumerate(emquiz):
    print(line)
    if ans == "2":
        score=score+1
        questionNumber=questionNumber+1
    elif ans=="1":
        questionNumber=questionNumber+1
    elif ans !="1" or ans !="2":
        print("You have entered an invalid character")
        easyMathsQuiz()
```

easyMathsQuiz()
print (score)

This is whats inside the .txt file:

What is 2+2-1? 1)3 2)4

What is 10+10? 1)30 2)20

What is 3*9? 1)27 2)36

What is 100/5? 1)25 2)20

What is 30-17? 1)23 2)13

My problem is:
Each line number basically represnts the question number. the first line i got to print but im just not sure how to make the next line print and i need the system to allow the user to input and of course it needs to check if their answer is correct. And i also have just absolutely no idea how to write code for it to go to the start of the question when they enter an invalid character rather than make the whole thing restart
Btw i cant seem to get the code to indent properly on here everything is indented correctly on my program